# passing values from multiple dropdownlist to a crystal report from vb.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I am using asp.net and vb.net

I have 3 dropdownlist which are sorting according to the previous dropdownlist.
Now my question is that.if i only select dropdownlist1 then it shows the details related to the selected value of dropdownlist1.
if i select dropdownlist1 and then dropdownlist2 then it shows the details related to the selected value of dropdownlist 2.
and if i select dropdownlist1,then dropdownlist2 and then dropdownlist3 then it shows the details of the selected value of the dropdownlist3.

Comment: Are you asking how to build a dynamic/cascading parameter set in Crystal Reports or how to pass the values that you've collected from your application's parameter set to Crystal Reports?

Comment: How about some code to show us how you are trying to pass the parameters?